# Is it possible to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for all polynomials of degree $n \le 4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Recenly I've been wondering whether it's possible to prove the FTA for all polynomials of degree $n \le 4$ without utilizing advanced maths but, at most, basic linear algebra (concepts such as eigenvectors, eigenvalues, determinants etc.). I've tried to give this some thought but I've been only able to make very naïve and futile statements such as "all real numbers can be represented as complex numbers " and "some quadratics and quartics, such as $p(x)=x^2 + 1$ and $p(x)=x^4 -1$, contain complex solutions". Now, I would be really greatful, if it is indeed possible to prove the FTA for all polynomials with degree $n \le 4$, if someone could provide a reference of some sort.

Comment: Pulling out the quadratic/cubic/quartic formula and showing that they are correct is a proof of this. The only sticking point is choosing the right branch of the radicals.

Comment: I vaguely remember doing this for cubics, back in 2010 when I was first discovering that, hey, if you think about things for awhile, hey presto, sometimes you work things out! Can't remember the details, but in retrospect the argument was probably circular, because it probably used facts about matrices with complex entries that relied on FTA to prove in the first place.

Comment: The Wikipedia has some nice proofs:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

Comment: The most elegant way is to use Liouville's Theorem.  You may start with the definition of holomorphic functions in a complex variable book.  An example is this one: http://www.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/~yasuda/ippansug/CV-bookfi.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Let $p\in\mathbb{R}[X]\setminus\mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial of degree at most $4$.

- If $\deg(p)=1$, then you can easily explicit the root of $p$.
- If $\deg(p)=2$, same remark.
- If $\deg(p)=3$, you can also explicit the roots of $p$ using [Cardano's method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function)
- If $\deg(p)=4$, you can also explicit the roots of $p$ using this time [Ferrari's method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation)

Note that if $\deg(p)\geqslant 5$, in the general case, you won't be able to find such formulas for the roots of $p$, it's the [Ruffini-Abel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)